# Can i set my Firebase Database to accept request from only one user per time? Xamarin Form C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I have this Firebase Database child for counting the register number in my app.

```
#Firebase
+Register
 -RegisterCount: 19
```

And this is my Xamarin form C# code for updating the RegisterCount whenever a user complete register.

```
#Code
var getR = fc.Child("Register").OnceSingleAsync<Register>();

fc.Child("Register").PutAsync(new Register{ RegisterCount = getR.Result.RegisterCount + 1});
```

However, i noticed that whenever i click register with multiple users at the same time, the RegisterCount only count once. Is there any solution to fix this duplicated problem or How to set my Firebase Database to process only 1 request at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made the solution for this case and here is the code i use.

```
private async void Register_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i.numberRe = "ReDB";
        FirebaseClient fc = new FirebaseClient(//Firebase Database Link);
        
        i.countRe = 0;

        var cfc = fc.Child(i.numberRe).OnceAsync<ReData>();
        foreach(var item in cfc.Result)
        {
            i.countRe = i.countRe + 1;
        }
        if(i.countRe < 200)
        {
            await fc.Child(i.numberRe).PostAsync(new ReData { User = "Test"});
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FinishView());
        }
        if(i.countJoin == 200)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Database is full", "ok");
        }
```

}

```
private async void CheckMember()
    {
        iCount = 0;
        
        FirebaseClient fbc = new FirebaseClient(//Firebase Database Link);
        var cfc2 = fbc.Child(i.numberRe).OnceAsync<ReData>();
        foreach(var item1 in cfc2.Result)
        {
            iCount = iCount + 1;
        }
       
        if (iCount > 200)
        {
            foreach (var item in cfc2.Result)
            {
                checkKey = item.Key;
                checkName = item.Object.User;

            }
            await fbc.Child(i.numberRe + "/" + checkKey).DeleteAsync();
            if(checkName == "Test")
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Database is 
full", "ok");
                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new 
RegisterView());
            }
            
        }
    }

public class ReData
{
public string User {get; set;}
public string Pw {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this approach completely solves the case where multiple user may be increment the count at almost the same time. If both users first read the current value (say `i`), and then both write their incremented value back, you'll end up with  `i + 1` instead of `i + 2`. To prevent this you'll need to use a transaction or increment (in the SDK) or (if you're using the REST API) an [`ETag`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests) or [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values).

Comment: I am not sure if this will work 100%, but as i tested it out (with 3 users at a time) it works well. Because the CheckMember() function start working Only After register is completed which means it will read all the overcounted registers, and delete them(bases on newest key), then return those users back to the register page.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure only one user can register at the same time, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions).

But in this case, you can also use the [atomic `increment` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments). I'm not sure if that is available in the Xamarin.Forms bindings, but *if* it is - it'll be more efficient than using a transaction.

Comment: Noted Sir i will test it out and let you know.

Comment: sir are the two options above can be used in Xamarin c#? i tried it, but i think it's not for Xamarin C#

Comment: As said: I'm not sure if `increment` is available in Xamarin.Forms. But transactions should be available on any platform. Can you link me to where you get the SDK from that you use?

Comment: fyi sir https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/

Comment: I don't see anything for the Firebase Realtime Database there. A deeper link would be appreciated.

Comment: these two links will provide you the info  sir:
1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/
2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseDatabase.net/

Comment: That package indeed doesn't seem to implement transactions, as shown in this old bug: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/issues/41. You'll have to come up with your own code that calls the REST API in that case, as transactions or increment are the only two ways to prevent the multi-user conflict that you asked about.

Comment: Sir i am thankful for your help and advices. I have come up with my own code solution to solve this case already. i finished solving it in like 10 hour.

Comment: Yes Sir. i have posted the answer already. It works really nice so far!